# Error importing MySQL package for Python

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, importerror, install-name-tool

I'm trying to import a MySQL module with python, more specifically Flask, though I receive an error. I'm using a virtual environment with my application. Here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../myapp/application.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 81, in load_module
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb.tb_next)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flaskext/mysql.py", line 3, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Referenced from: /Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I can see in the error it says `Library not loaded: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so`. As I'm using a virtual environment that path is incorrect. It should be `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so`.

Is there a way to change this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I found there was a terminal command on OSX to change the library location:

```
 sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/
```

though after hitting enter I get this:

```
Usage: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/install_name_tool [-change old new] ... [-rpath old new] ... [-add_rpath new] ... [-delete_rpath old] ... [-id name] input
```

I don't appear to be entering the command wrong, what is the issue?

Comment: how did you created the virtualenv? Does it use the system's site_packages (`--system-site-packages` in a new virtualenv version, enabled by default in older version ), or is it completely isolated?

Comment: Yes, It is completely isolated from the system.

Comment: You're missing the last argument to `install_name_tool` command. Your command should read like, `install_name_tool -change old new input`.

Comment: So how would I go about changing the library that  `_mysql.so`? refers to?

Comment: Try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include /lib/python2.7/site-packages/. This is a temporary, environment-specific way to achieve the permanent effect of install_name_tool. In bash: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

Comment: did you install the tool AFTER you activated your virtual environment?  when you activate a virtual environment you will need to install all additional 3rd party packages again unless you are using and activating a shared virtualenv.  if you have not installed the tool after activating the do that and run your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, try avoiding system python install like a plague. Yes, even basing your virtualenvs on it. It will too often generate hard to understand problems.

I recommend getting [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then installing python and mysql for the headers:

```
brew install python
brew install mysql
```

And then basing your virtualenv on python from brew:

```
virtualenv venv --python /usr/local/bin/python
```

I know, it's a little more hoops to jump through, but it will make your development process that much easier. Not to mention `brew` is a great aid to a developer in its own right.

I just checked if it worked, it took me two minutes to get a working MySQLdb.

Comment: Worked fantastically and fixed the problem without any issues, great answer.